# How do I perform Date Comparison in EF query?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, linq-to-entities, datetime-comparison

Please help.
I am trying to figure out how to use DATE or DATETIME for comparison in a linq query.

Example:
If I wanted all Employee names for those who started before today, I would do something like this in SQL:

```
SELECT EmployeeNameColumn
FROM EmployeeTable
WHERE StartDateColumn.Date <= GETDATE() //Today
```

But what about linq?

```
DateTime startDT = //Today

var EmployeeName =  
from e in db.employee
where e.StartDateColumn <= startDT
```

The above WHERE doesn't work:

> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That should work. Are you sure that there isn't another part of the query that triggered the exception? I have several instances of queries of the form

```
var query = from e in db.MyTable
            where e.AsOfDate <= DateTime.Now.Date
            select e;
```

in my code.

Comment: This worked: WHERE StartDateColumn <= GETDATE() //Today
This did not: WHERE StartDateColumn.Date <= GETDATE() //Today

I had .Date in my statement - I must have been over thinking the issue.

Thank you.
kam

Comment: This is not the problem - e.AsofDate.Date is the problem (compare only the date portion - on both sides...

Answer (score 90):

Use the class `DbFunctions` for trimming the time portion.

```
using System.Data.Entity;

var bla = (from log in context.Contacts
           where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(log.ModifiedDate) 
                              ==  DbFunctions.TruncateTime(today.Date)
           select log).FirstOrDefault();
```

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/84d4e18b-7545-419b-9826-53ff1a0e2a62/

Comment: Was struggling with this, decided to use an extension method, just to find later on about this -.-

Comment: This should have been the answer

Comment: EntityFunctions was obsoleted, replaced by DbFunctions, updated answer to reflect this

Comment: EntityFunctions was replaced in EF 6.0. So if you're still on 4.5 or earlier (like myself) you should still use EntityFunctions.

Comment: how you seen what sql query is DbFunctions.TruncateTime generating:
((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[InspectionReportInfo_Date], 102), 102)) = '2015-02-10T00:00:00' 

this kills any index and I would avoid it... https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/45f496e1-550d-4638-9673-127e406e2352/entityfunctions-truncatetime-inefficiency?forum=adodotnetentityframework&prof=required

Comment: Agree. This should have been the answer

Answer (score 10):

It may be due to the date in the database being nullable. Try this:

```
var EmployeeName =
from e in db.employee
where e.StartDateColumn.Value <= startDT
```

Comment: The ".Value" was the epiphany for me.

Answer (score 8):

You can check the condition like this

```
var nextDay = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);

var query = from e in db.MyTable
            where e.AsOfDate >= DateTime.Today && e.AsOfDate < nextDay 
            select e;
```

here you'll get the records on AsOfDate date as we checking between today(00:00:00) and tommorow(00:00:00) we'll get today's date record only what ever may be the time...

Answer (score 6):

You can not use .Date

If you would like to check for today you can create a datetime with no time

```
DateTime myDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
var e = (from mds in myEntities.Table
         where mds.CreateDateTime >= myDate
         select mds).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious to the error message saying `'Date'`, when you're passing a `'DateTime'`. Could it be that `'StartDateColumn'` is actually a `'Date'`, rather than a `'DateTime'` in the database? That might mess up the comparison...

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
DateTime dd = DateTime.Parse("08/13/2010 00:00:00");
var data = from n in ContributionEligibilities
           where n.ModifiedDateTime.Date >= DateTime.Parse("08/13/2010").Date
           select n; 
data.Dump("Result") ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using a LinqDataSource and I had problems getting my query with a Date Comparison in it to execute without errors.  The answer is to use the WhereAddParameters function and add the test value as a strongly typed parameter.

See the example below where I am matching a groupid and checking to see if the StopDate in my record is greater that or equal to a Date/Time stamp of now.

I am using this code fragment currently and it works like a charm.

```
LinqCampaigns.WhereParameters.Add("StopDate", System.Data.DbType.Date, DateTime.Now.ToString())
LinqCampaigns.Where = "GroupId = " & myGrp & " &&  " & "StopDate >= @StopDate"
```

Works like a charm....

Answer (score 1):

use a local variable to store the Date value and then use that variable in the query:

`DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;
  from scheme in context.schemes
   where scheme.EndDate > today
   select scheme`

Answer (score 0):

.Date did not work, but **.Day** did for me.

```
var query = from o in Payments
    where o.Order.OrderDate.Day != o.PaymentDate.Day
    orderby o.Order.OrderDate
    select new
    {
     o.Order.OrderID,
     o.Order.OrderDate,
     o.PaymentDate,      
     o.Order.FirstName,
     o.Order.LastName,
     o.Order.CustomerID
    };


query.Dump();
```

Comment: This is probably ***not*** what you want. It will simply get the Day of the Month. So, for instance, Jan 01 & Feb 01 both have the same 'Day' component value, despite actually being different days in real time.

Answer (score -1):

ensure that you check null value like this :

```
 '(from mm in _db.Calls 
   where mm.Professionnal.ID.Equals(proid)
   && mm.ComposedDate.HasValue &&
   (mm.ComposedDate.Value >= datemin) && (mm.ComposedDate.Value <= date)
   select mm).ToArray();'
```