# compare the dates with linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework, date

I have this code:

```
   i.SpesaVitto = db.TDP_NotaSpeseSezB.Where(p => p.GiornoFine == null && 
                ((DateTime)p.Giorno).Date == ((DateTime)i.Data).Date &&
                p.MissioneID == missioneID).Sum(p => p.Costo);
```

If i launch it i obtain this error:

```
The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

how can i compare the datetimes field without the hours part

thanks

Comment: What database system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is certainly not the most efficient way to do it, but you can try something like:

```
i.SpesaVitto = db.TDP_NotaSpeseSezB.Where(p => p.GiornoFine == null && 
            (new DateTime((p.Giorno as DateTime).Year, (p.Giorno as DateTime).Month, (p.Giorno as DateTime).Day) == (new DateTime((i.Data as DateTime).Year, (i.Data as DateTime).Month, (i.Data as DateTime).Day) &&
            p.MissioneID == missioneID).Sum(p => p.Costo);
```

Depending on the requirements I would probably implement something cleaner and faster but it would depend on how the dates are stored in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088212/linq-how-do-i-perform-date-comparison-in-a-linq-query) it looks like the syntax error may be in your SQL, not in your LINQ.  The asker in that question had written:

```
SQL ------
Select
 EmployeeNameColumn
From
EmployeeTable
WHERE StartDateColumn.Date <= GETDATE() //Today
SQL ------
```

When they should have written:

```
SQL ------
Select
 EmployeeNameColumn
From
EmployeeTable
WHERE StartDateColumn <= GETDATE() //Today
SQL -
```

Answer (score 0):

solution for your problem will be the "SqlFunctions class and DateDiff" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx