# Simple way to compare Dates in DateTime attribute using Entity Framework 4 and Linq queries

Tags: c#, datetime, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to run the following bit of code, but the comparison fails by not handing my the entities I expect it to.

It's comparing `06/09/2011 0:00:00` to `06/09/2011 12:25:00`, the latter being my databases record value. So that's why the comparison is failing and I'm not getting the records I need.

I'm just trying to compare if the dates match up, I'm don't care about the time.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;
var newAuctionsResults = repo.FindAllAuctions()
                        .Where(a => a.IsActive == true || a.StartTime.Value == today)
                        .ToList();
```

How can I compare only the dates?

If use the .Date property in the .StartTime.Value part, I get an exception:

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
>   Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties
>   are supported.

Comment: Maybe this question will help? LINQ | How do I perform Date Comparison in a Linq Query? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088212/linq-how-do-i-perform-date-comparison-in-a-linq-query

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the individual members:

```
var newAuctionsResults = repo.FindAllAuctions()
                        .Where(a => a.IsActive == true 
                                    || (a.StartTime.Value.Year == todayYear
                                        && a.StartTime.Value.Month == todayMonth
                                        && a.StartTime.Value.Day == todayDay))
                        .ToList();
```

...or use any of [the other methods/properties supported in L2E](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx).

Comment: It is being used for equal operator. What if I need to check greater than and less than operator.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime()` under the namespace `System.Data.Objects`

Ex.

```
db.Orders.Where(i => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(i.OrderFinishDate) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(dtBillDate) && i.Status == "B")
```

Works like charm.

Comment: How do you write UnitTests then?

Comment: EntityFunctions are now obsolete, use DbFunctions instead!

Answer (score -1):

try

```
DateTime todayStart = DateTime.Now.Date;
DateTime todayEnd = DateTime.Now;
var newAuctionsResults = repo.FindAllAuctions()
                        .Where(a => a.IsActive == true || (a.StartTime.Value >= todayStart && a.StartTime.Value <= todayEnd))
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score -2):

You could convert using

```
DateTime.ToShortDateString()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx

This would neglect the Time.

Then compare the two Strings.

```
if(string1 == string2)
{
 //Do Something
}
```

Comment: [Not supported in L2E](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx), I'm afraid.