# Datetime comparison before and after

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2005, entity-framework-5, dynamic-linq

I'm using dynamic linq to build a where clause for a moderately complex search, and I've run into a problem with dates.

I want the user to be able to filter on the "date created" searching for anything either before that date, on that date, or after that date.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7320703/1324019) which I used to construct a dynamic query looking like this: `.Year == @0.Year && created.Month == @0.Month && created.Day == @0.Day)"`. This works fine for searching for dates which are exactly equal, but doesn't hold up when trying to search for something before or after. The furthest I've gotten is doing `"(created.Year >= @0.Year && created.Month >= @0.Month && created.Day > @0.Day)` which doesn't work for anything outside the current month (If I searched for (after today), it would only show me results with day > 27 even if they're in a month after the date I searched for.)

I tried using `DateTime.Compare` as well but that didn't work, nor did trying to compare DateTime.Date`.

Is there any way I can accomplish this short of using T-SQL directly?

EDIT: with `"(created.Date == @0.Date)"`

[image]

Comment: Why not simply `created.Date > @yourDate.Date` or `created.Date < @yourDate.Date`? (Assuming `created` and `@yourDate` are of type `DateTime`)

Comment: Because Linq to Entities doesn't support that...

Comment: I would be *very* surprised if it supported `.Day`, `.Month` and `.Year`, but not `.Date`.

Comment: @Corak prepare to be surprised then, see my edit.

Comment: Okay, you got me surprised. Well, then have `@yourDate = whatEverYouGotFromUser.Date` and then `created < @yourDate` or `created > @yourDate`.

Comment: @Corak problem is then that breaks equals (date) so I was hoping for a better way. However, if nothing else comes up I'll use that - thanks!

Comment: for equals, you might be able to do something like `created > @yourDate && created < @yourDate.AddDays(1)` ... but now I'm not sure anymore. ^^; you might need to make `@yourDate.AddDays(1)` another variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using my existing code for "On" comparisons, and just doing a strict `>` or `<` for  before and after as Corak suggested.

```
if (Comparison == ComparisonType.Equals) {
    return string.Format("({0}.Year {2} @{1}.Year && {0}.Month {2} @{1}.Month && {0}.Day {2} @{1}.Day)", FieldName, index, ComparisonType.Equals.Evaluate()); //workaround for "exactly equals date"
} else if (Comparison == ComparisonType.Less_Than) {
       Value = ((DateTime)Value).Minimize(); //set the time values of the date to the minimums (00:00:00 000)
} else if (Comparison == ComparisonType.Greater_Than) {
       Value = ((DateTime)Value).Maximize(); //set the time values of the date to the maximums (23:59:59 999)
}

return string.Format("({0} {1} @{2})", FieldName, Comparison.Evaluate(), index);
```