# Error in comparing DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, linq-to-entities

My first attempt to compare `DateTime`

```
var searchResult = new PagedData<SAMPLE_STOCK>
{
Data = _db.SAMPLE_STOCK.Where(m => m.LAST_UPDATED.Date == lastUpdate.Date)
};
return PartialView(searcReasult);
```

it gives the following error

```
The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to 
Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation 
properties are supported.
```

Then I write following code

```
var searchResult = new PagedData<SAMPLE_STOCK>
{
Data = _db.SAMPLE_STOCK.Where(m => m.LAST_UPDATED.Day == lastUpdate.Day 
                                && m.LAST_UPDATED.Month == lastUpdate.Month
                                && m.LAST_UPDATED.Year==lastUpdate.Year)
};
```

It works fine. My question is.... What is the difference between these??

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736252/using-datetime-in-linq-to-entities

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320608/simple-way-to-compare-dates-in-datetime-attribute-using-entity-framework-4-and-l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is thrown because your predicate cannot be translated into SQL.
If you cast it to Enumerable, it could work because you force to use linq2object filtering, but I think your second query is more efficient than this:

```
var searchResult = new PagedData<SAMPLE_STOCK>
{
    Data = _db.SAMPLE_STOCK.AsEnumrable().Where(m => m.LAST_UPDATED.Date == lastUpdate.Date)
};
return PartialView(searcReasult);
```

It's your choice, this option provides less code, but more memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

The message

`The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to 
Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation 
properties are supported.`

is pretty self explanatory. SQL won't know how to fetch Date property of a DateTime type.
It can work with DateTime. It can work with Integers. 
In you case, you'll have to make it work with integers.

As far as performance it concerned.. I don't see any bad impacts.

PS:The support of `Date` datatype in SQL is not related to this.