# entityframework can't return the records in database with datetime.now condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to return some records from the database using this query :

```
        ViewBag.TrafficEnter = _iTrafficRepository.Get().Where(i => i.Type == "ورود" && i.SubmitDateTime == DateTime.Now).ToList();
```

[image]

Here you can see my database records:

[image]

But the problem is the query doesn't return any values .why ?

Comment: your query is matching time also..that is why it is not returning anything..just compare date only.

Comment: You need to put your code in the question, not an image of it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i did that.tnx

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla you mean i add a date statement to the end of my datetime.now ?for example datetime.now.date?

Comment: As @KartikeyaKhosla noted, you wont ever have any records that match `DateTime.Now` (how could they be added the exact millisecond you call this query) - are you wanting records created `DateTime.Today`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have records with the value of my cndition

Comment: @EhsanAkbar No, that will fail, as EF can't translate DateTime.Now.Date to SQL. Use the [DbFunctions class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.aspx)

Comment: @EhsanAkbar..check this [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320608/simple-way-to-compare-dates-in-datetime-attribute-using-entity-framework-4-and-l)

Comment: @EhsanAkbar, That's impossible. You could not be adding a record to your database the exact millisecond you execute the query

Comment: @StephenMuecke i just need the date value not the time .

Comment: So do you just want records that have a `SubmitDateTime` equal to today's date (ignoring the time)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes

Comment: @StephenMuecke in my other application i use this query and it work correctly ,but in this my project i don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: Then its `.Where(i.SubmitDateTime.Date == DateTime.Today)` assuming your `Get()` method has materialized the collection.

Comment: @StephenMuecke let me check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112745/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ehsan-akbar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparing the `DateTime` values in your database with the value of `DateTime.Now` which returns the current time (including milliseconds) and could never match any of the values in the table.

Modify you query to select values in a range

```
var minDate = DateTime.Today; // returns today's with time component set to 00:00:00
var maxDate = minDate.AddDays(1);
ViewBag.TrafficEnter = _iTrafficRepository.Get()
    .Where(i => i.Type == "ورود" && i.SubmitDateTime >= minDate && i.SubmitDateTime < maxDate).ToList();
```

Assuming today's date is 24th May 2016, it will return all 17 records shown in your image.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with DateTime.Now is that implies a very small date range that is equal to the smallest division of it's precision, in this case 1 millisecond. Unless your record is created with almost exactly the same value as DateTime.Now you'll never get a match.

You have two solutions (that may not be appropriate to your needs);

Firstly rather than matching an exact dateTime, try to match a range e.g. 1 hour before/after DateTime.Now. This would have the advantage of giving you control over range.

Alternatively you could try matching the date value (DateTime.Now.Date) with the date of your record.