# Linq-to-SQL to search only DATE portions of a date 

Tags: sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, date, comparison

I need to get data based on date range like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE 
myDate >= 'May 17 2012' AND 
myDate <= 'May 17 2012'
```

I have written this query in LINQ , the issue is that LINQ is converting this query to:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE 
myDate >= 'May 17 2012 12:00:00:000AM' AND 
myDate <= 'May 17 2012 12:00:00:000AM'
```

The problem is that LINQ is also considering the time part but I need to search only on date part.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just wanted to share with you that i found the solution!

The EntityFunctions provide us TruncateTime(), which can used for this purpose.

> EntityFunctions.TruncateTime

```
 from e in MyContext.MyTable.Where(a =>
 EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.DateTimeColumn) ==   
 EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now))  select e;
```

**EDIT:**
For EntityFramework 6 and above:

```
 from e in MyContext.MyTable.Where(a =>
 DbFunctions.TruncateTime(a.DateTimeColumn) ==   
 DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now))  select e;
```

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9642321/265167).

Comment: FYI to anyone looking at this now: for EntityFramework 6, "EntityFunctions" has been deprecated and replaced by "DbFunctions"

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this answer today also - found it here
[Comparing Dates in Linq To SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/08/22/comparing-dates-in-linq-to-sql.aspx)

I also double checked with the profiler to make sure its being translated to SQL

```
from e in MyContext.MyTable.Where(a => a.DateTimeColumn.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
select e;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

```
from t in context.MyTable
where t.MyDate <= maxDate.AddDays(1)
select t
```

or

```
from t in context.MyTable
where t.MyDate.Date <= maxDate.Date
select t
```

The first might give better performance since the second might not be able to use your database indexes correctly. But the second is more obvious in intent.

Comment: hmmm. let me try the second one looks OK to me.

Comment: Error:
The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually searching *only* by date part; behind the scenes that date is a `DateTime`.
So, to get the rows for one day think of it this way:

*I want to get all rows that have `MyDate` greater or equal to May 17 midnight and less than May 18 midnight.*

The query below does that.

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2012, 05, 17);
var endDate = new DateTime(2012, 05, 18);
var result = 
from row in context.MyTable
where row.MyDate >= startDate &&
      row.MyDate < endDate
select row;
```