# Using DateTime in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, datetime, linq-to-entities

I have a PostgreSQL database that interacts with the program through Entity Framework Code First.

Database contains a table "users" that has column "visit" type of DateTime.

The application is described as;

```
public class Users
{    ...
    [Required]
    [Column("visit")]
    public DateTime VisitDate
    ...
}
```

I trying to run this query;

```
var rslt = context.Visitors.Where(v => v.VisitDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date).ToList()
```

But getting an exception: `NotSupportedException`

What's wrong?

Comment: can you post the inner details of your exception?

Comment: you can use `var rslt = context.Visitors.Where(v => v.VisitDate.Date == DateTime.Now).ToList()`

Comment: @saravanan I think you may mean `Datetime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`DateTime.Date` property is not supported. You have to use [`SqlFunctions.DatePart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487171.aspx) method instead. It will end up with `DATEPART` `TSQL` method within generated SQL query.

```
var rslt = context.Visitors
                  .Where(v => SqlFunctions.DatePart("year", v.VisitDate) == SqlFunctions.DatePart("year", DateTime.Now))
                  .Where(v => SqlFunctions.DatePart("dayofyear", v.VisitDate) == SqlFunctions.DatePart("dayofyear", DateTime.Now))
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I get NotSupportedException again. But message contains other information: The specified method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] DatePart(System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])" on the type "System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions" cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression. Maybe it's PostgreSQL's problem?

Answer (score 13):

Use the class EntityFunction for trimming the time portion.

```
using System.Data.Objects;    

var bla = (from log in context.Contacts
           where EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(log.ModifiedDate) ==  EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(today.Date)
           select log).FirstOrDefault();
```

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/84d4e18b-7545-419b-9826-53ff1a0e2a62/

Comment: Please see answer from Tim S below for the latest implementation using DbFunctions instead

Answer (score 5):

Mayur Borad's answer (IMHO more correct than the accepted answer) has become out of date:

`System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityFunctions` is obsolete. You should use `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions` instead.

```
var today = DateTime.Today; // (Time already removed)

var bla = context.Contacts
    .FirstOrDefault(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ModifiedDate) == today);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the LINQ provider is trying to convert `DateTime.Now.Date` to a database method, which it cannot do by default. The trick to doing date comparison is to create a `DateTime` instance that has its time component set to the default value. You can get more information [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/84d4e18b-7545-419b-9826-53ff1a0e2a62/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088212/how-do-i-perform-date-comparison-in-ef-query).