# System.NotSupportedException using DateTime? in Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, datetime, notsupportedexception

I have a `System.NotSupportedException` using `DateTime`? in `Linq to Entities`.

My original method looks like this:

```
public TransportOrderLine GetLastTransportOrderLine(bool isDriver, int? driverId, int? haulierId , DateTime date, IDatabaseContext db)
{
    var lines =
        db.Query<TransportOrderLine>()
          .Where(x => ((isDriver && x.TransportOrder.DriverId == driverId) ||
                      (!isDriver && x.TransportOrder.HaulierId == haulierId)) &&
                      x.StartDatePlanned.HasValue &&
                      EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.StartDatePlanned) <= date)
                      .ToList();

    return lines.OrderByDescending(x => x.TransportOrder.Sequence)
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.Sequence).LastOrDefault();
}
```

For some reason, I'm having an exception (`NotSupportedException`) when linq to entities executes the `DateTime` part.

`TransportOrderLine.StartDatePlanned` is of type `DateTime`?.

I also split my code like this already:

```
var lines = db.Query<TransportOrderLine>()
              .Where(x => ((isDriver && x.TransportOrder.DriverId == driverId) ||
                         (!isDriver && x.TransportOrder.HaulierId == haulierId)))
              .ToList(); //ok


lines = lines.Where(x => x.StartDatePlanned.HasValue).ToList(); //ok

lines = lines.Where(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.StartDatePlanned)<= date)
             .ToList(); //error here
```

I also tried this:

```
lines = lines.Where(x => (DateTime)EntityFunctions
             .TruncateTime((DateTime)x.StartDatePlanned.Value)
             .Value <= date).ToList(); //error here
```

Anyone knows a solution.

Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: Try `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.StartDatePlanned.Value)` ?

Comment: Tim. Tang, I have tried that already. See the last code block.

Comment: see this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736252/using-datetime-in-linq-to-entities

Comment: @IgorSemin `EntityFunctions` exists *specifically* to be functions that the database knows about.

Comment: @IgorSemin this will convert `LINQ2EF` to `LINQ2Object` ,and sql server do know what is `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`

Comment: sorry guys, i was wrong

Comment: I did something based on Igor his answer.

var lines =
               db.Query<TransportOrderLine>()
                   .Where(
                      *queryToDb*).ToList().Where(x => (DateTime)x.StartDatePlanned.Value <= date);

This works fine now! Thx

Comment: Please, answer yourself and mark as valid, or delete this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
var lines =
    db.Query<TransportOrderLine>()
      .Where(x => ((isDriver && x.TransportOrder.DriverId == driverId) ||
                  (!isDriver && x.TransportOrder.HaulierId == haulierId)) &&
                  x.StartDatePlanned.HasValue)
                  .ToList().Where(x => (DateTime)x.StartDatePlanned.Value <= date);
```