# Comparing dates in linq

Tags: c#, html, forms, linq, linq-to-entities

I would like to query the db for items with a date greater than or equal to a given date.

The date in the db is a datetime and records time.

If the user enters the search string "1/30/2014", they expect entries that occurred at any time on that date to be returned. However, anything that has a time after 12 am is not returned.

I know I could simply add a day to the search string, but is there a more appropriate way?

```
if (form["closedend"] != "")
{
     DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(form["closedend"]);
     traces = traces.Where(s => s.date_Closed >= d);
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [`Date` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) to truncate the time part:

```
 traces = traces.Where(s => s.date_Closed.Date <= d.Date);
```

On this way you'd include this day since both `DateTime`s are midnight.

**Update** if you use LINQ to Entities `DateTime.Date` is not supported, you could use this solution: [Using DateTime in LINQ to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736252/using-datetime-in-linq-to-entities)

```
.Where(s => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(s.date_Closed) <=  EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d))
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP is using Linq-to-Entities (they mention a db), but if they are `Date` will not work.

Comment: I ended up using DbFunctions as EntityFunctions is deprecated. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Warning CS0618 `EntityFunctions` is obsolete: 'This class has been replaced by System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.'
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(AnDateTime)`

Answer (score 0):

You said

> with a date greater than or equal to a given date

but in your code you write

```
s.date_Closed <= d
```

I think you must change `<=` by `>=` to obtain dates greater or equal to d, now you're getting dates less or equal to d.

Answer (score 0):

**For this example you don't need neccessary any other dll**. You can implement other function, which return `bool`, f.e:

```
public bool MyFunction(DateTime s)
{
   DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(Your constructor);
   return (s.date_Closed >= d);
}

var query = from obj in traces
            where MyFunction(obj.date_Closed.Date)
            select obj;
```

or:

```
var query = traces.Where(p => MyFunction(p.data_Closed.Date));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(StartDateTime)` To remove the time from datetime.

```
    if (form["closedend"] != "")
    {
         DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(form["closedend"]);
         traces = traces.Where(s => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.date_Closed) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(d));
    }
```