# System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified type member 'StartDateTime' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, notsupportedexception

After running my project visual studio has shown me this System.NotSupportedException in my Index.cshtml

[image]

Here's my HomeController

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var events = this.db.Events
            .OrderBy(e => e.StartDateTime)
            .Where(e => e.IsPublic)
            .Select(e => new EventViewModel()
            {
                Id = e.Id,
                Title = e.Title,
                Duration = e.Duration,
                Author= e.Author.FullName,
                Location = e.Location
            });

        var upcomingEvents = events.Where(e => e.StartDateTime > DateTime.Now);
        var passedEvents = events.Where(e => e.StartDateTime <= DateTime.Now);
        return View(new UpcomingPassedEventsViewModel()
        {
            UpcomingEvents = upcomingEvents,
            PassedEvents = passedEvents
        });
    }
}
```

}

Here is my EventViewModel.cs

```
public class EventViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan? Duration { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your event only seems to hold id, title, duration, author and location - no startdatetime

Comment: You have to provide the code for your `EventViewModel` class. It is very likely that the `StartDateTime` property is not mapped to a DB column. But to check that we need the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform Date Comparison in EF query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088212/how-do-i-perform-date-comparison-in-ef-query)

Comment: I added my EventViewModel

Answer (score 0):

You're projecting your entities into a view model. That's a good thing to do, but afterwards you can't refine the query for your viewmodel again. You're querying on `EventViewModel.StartDateTime`, which you don't even map.

You need to add the query before mapping. Of course you don't want to duplicate the mapping code, so put it in a method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
    var events = this.db.Events
                     .OrderBy(e => e.StartDateTime)
                     .Where(e => e.IsPublic);

    var upcomingEvents = events.Where(e => e.StartDateTime > DateTime.Now);
    var passedEvents = events.Where(e => e.StartDateTime <= DateTime.Now);

    return View(new UpcomingPassedEventsViewModel()
    {
        UpcomingEvents = upcomingEvents.Select(Map).ToList(),
        PassedEvents = passedEvents.Select(Map).ToList()
    });
}

private EventViewModel Map(EventDataModel e)
{
    return new EventViewModel()
    {
        Id = e.Id,
        Title = e.Title,
        Duration = e.Duration,
        Author= e.Author.FullName,
        Location = e.Location
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"BugFinder" answered my question. My events doesn't hold StartDateTime. So, here is the answer

```
var events = this.db.Events
            .OrderBy(e => e.StartDateTime)
            .Where(e => e.IsPublic)
            .Select(e => new EventViewModel()
            {
                Id = e.Id,
                Title = e.Title,
                StartDateTime = e.StartDateTime,
                Duration = e.Duration,
                Author= e.Author.FullName,
                Location = e.Location
            });
```